# What is this indicator for?

Tags: indicators

Can someone help? If that indicator is light up, what does mean? The first one, next to red arrow.
[image]

Comment: That symbol usually means "open contact" but without vehicle etc difficult to say...

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The vehicle is DAF Berkoff 2002, when we start the engine this indicator doesn't switch off. What can be the reason for this, and is it safe to drive it like this or not.

Comment: This is on a bus? Do you have the service manual? Why not have whoever does the fleet work take a look at it? If you're transporting people it's probably in your best interest not to have it in service until the issue is resolved.

Comment: Yes is a bus, we are buying it from Netherlands, and we have to take it to another country where would be checked properly. We are just short in time and we are thinking if we can go with this issue and resolve it when we get to our final destination.

Comment: I'd say as long as the engine runs and all of your safety features like air brakes, lights, horns etc... work than it's fine until you get it to your fleet mechanic.

Comment: Seems to be linked to DAF Actia - but I don't find a legend yet...

Comment: Your engine cover may not be latched properly, or the contact sensor for it is defective. Open/remove the engine cover and touch the contact, see if the light goes out.